# dc.js and bootstrap grid, chart width sizing different between chrome and firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to realize a simple dashboard but I am experiencing width issues between firefox and chrome (I am quite un-experienced in this area). Everything works perfectly on firefox, but on chrome it is completely stretched.

This is the selected part I have in html:

```
<body class="application">

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">Dashboard with &hearts;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">

          <!-- Test Chart -->
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="chart-wrapper">
              <div class="chart-title">
                Test Chart
              </div>
              <div class="chart-stage">
                <!--<div id="chart"></div>-->
                <div class="row">
                  <div id="chart"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div id="volume-chart"></div>
                  <p class="muted pull-right" style="margin-right: 15px;">select a time range to zoom in</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

And the javascript one:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/data")
    .await(makeGraphs);


function makeGraphs(error, recordsJson) {

    // Clean data
    var records = recordsJson;

    var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M");
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(records[0].date));

    records.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = new Date(d.date);
    });

    // Slice data to ease debugging
    records = records.slice(0, 2000);

    // Crossfilter instance
    ndx = crossfilter(records);

    // Define Dimensions
    var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.date; });
    var prodPowDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.prodPow; });
    var consPowDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.consPow; });

    // Define Groups
    var consByDate = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.cons; });
    var prodByDate = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.prod; });
    // Group by total volume within date dimension
    var volumeByDateDim = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.cons; });


    // Min and max dates to be used in the charts
    var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0]["date"];
    var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0]["date"];

    // Charts instance
    var chart = dc.lineChart("#chart");
    var volumeChart = dc.barChart('#volume-chart');


    chart
        .renderArea(true)
        /* Make the chart as big as the bootstrap grid by not setting ".width(960)" */
        .height(350)
        .transitionDuration(1000)
        .margins({top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 25, left: 40})
        .dimension(dateDim)
        /* Grouped data to represent and label to use in the legend */
        .group(consByDate, "Consumed")
        /* Function to access grouped-data values in the chart */
        .valueAccessor(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })
        /* x-axis range */
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
        /* Auto-adjust y-axis */
        .elasticY(true)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
        /* When on, you can't visualize values, when off you can filter data */
        .brushOn(false)
        /* Add another line to the chart; pass (i) group, (ii) legend label and (iii) value accessor */
        .stack(prodByDate, "Produced", function(d) { return d.value; })
        /* Range chart to link the brush extent of the range with the zoom focus of the current chart. */
        .rangeChart(volumeChart)
        /* TODO test them */
        //.mouseZoomable(true)
        //.round(d3.time.month.round)
        //.xUnits(d3.time.months)
        //.xAxisLabel("Year")
        //.yAxis().ticks(4)
        ;

    volumeChart//.width(990)
        .height(60)
        .margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 40})
        .dimension(dateDim)
        .group(volumeByDateDim)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(1)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
        //.round(d3.time.month.round)
        .alwaysUseRounding(true)
        //.xUnits(d3.time.months);


    // Render all graphs
    dc.renderAll();
};
```

In the chart customization I excluded `.width` because I noticed that in this way firefox was using the whole bootstrap `col-sm-12` and stretching the chart there...
Now with chrome this is not happening and I am not sure how to make this behavior persist with other browsers...all things I tried failed and the only option I could use is to use a fixed width that would look bad on a smaller screen...

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Hi, please use the dc.js tag for questions about the charting library - dc is quite something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright since I don't get any better answer, I will post the "quick&dirty" solution I found after some struggling with viewBox and similar options.

Just using this:

```
<div id="chart" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

For the index.html did the trick, now the chart displays on the full width of the page on both firefox, chrome and edge.

I also used this:

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%;">
```

for the row before the " section to avoid the horizontal bar from displaying.

The only issue that remains is that this is not very responsive, if I resize the browser page, the chart will remain of the same size and the horizontal bar won't appear...anyway I can survive with that for now, so problem solved.